# How to managing data and memory in Winform .Net Application?

Tags: .net

I am developing a windows application in which i have a grid control and i want to display different query output from my MS access database.
I have 12 queries which has a result of around 75 columns and 1000 rows
There are different menus to call and display this query results

If i read the query each time i click on the menu and load it by accessing the database and takes around 15 seconds. To avoid this dealy, i plan to load all the queries in memory when the application starts, basically create a dataset and store all the tables into that, now the display and access through different queries becomes faster.

My question is - Is this right what i am doing? if not any other better ways to handle this?
Will moving to WPF help? or any other things i need to take care.

Please help me and sorry if it is a dumb question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the databases are created to store the data and query efficiently. Having the same structure of the data in memory tables and querying similarly usually lead to lower performance. But if you change the structure of the data (create temporary tables or just store the results of the queries) then it is completely different case, but similarly, the performance should be quite similar (this time the memory cache will be better - although the database can cache query result in memory as well). This is with assumption that the database is correctly designed (mainly, indices are ok and used by the queries).

As far as I know, the difference in performance between WPF and WinForms is negligible comparing to the amount of time you mentioned (15 seconds). Both WPF and WinForms display the amount of controls that fits on the screen in a fractions of second. There are, of course, some caveats, but both WPF and WinForms have enough of them to be considered equally applicable applicable for your app.

My recommendation is to optimise queries as much as possible, considering creating temporary tables for frequently used data, and then cache the results in memory (no joins in memory!, unless you aware of b-trees). Then fetch only data which is required (do not fetch all 1000 records, fetch first 20 and display them immediately) and display it (reuse controls), fetching in background thread, when necessary. Continue fetching data in background threads trying to predict what user will do and which data might be requested.

TLTR: 1) optimise, then 2) cache, 3) fetch in background, 4) reuse UI controls, 5) display only what is visible.

Comment: `the difference in performance between WPF and WinForms is negligible ` -  You might want to watch [this short clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA)

Comment: @HighCore - thanks for the video. But if we are talking about populating a huge listboxes, then we should talk about databinding - creating a 20K list and assigning listbox.DataBinding property populates WinForms listbox in less than a second.

Comment: @AlexAtNet thanks for the inputs, i will definetly consider temp tables and see how it goes..